# Android screen capture problem in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-capture

I am having trouble using the "Screen Capture" function in Eclipse to capture an Android screen shot.  I have the correct tab open, and when I click the screen capture icon, the box pops up and just stays on "Capturing..." but the display never changes from a white box with an X through it.

I have USB debugging turned on on the phone and I have the correct device selected in Eclipse..any other tips?  Thanks!

Comment: I find that this command works on my Moto Droid (854x480) but not on my GTab (1200x600).  Perhaps it has something to do with the resolution.

Comment: Similar problem, turned off 'Use host GPU' in the virtual device and issue was resolved

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to your android sdk install folder.  Open the Tools folder and find DDMS.  Run DDMS and use the Screen Capture option from the Device pull down menu.  This is the native tool that Eclipse tries to use and it works better natively.

Comment: If your working with android 4.4 emulator, this is bug, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62284

Answer (score 0):

On the screen capture window, click done, then reopen the screen capture dialog.  I have to go through this process every time I want screen caps, for some reason it doesn't connect to device on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, also when Logcat ceases to work: When I disable and re-enable the debug mode on the device, everything is working again.