# DDMS Screen capture does not work

Tags: android, ddms, screen-capture

I cannot get the "Devices" screen capture (as shown in DDMS perspective) to work with my Archos A80 (it works with a Samsung Galaxy). 
I tried the suggestions mentioned in [Android screen capture problem in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433554/android-screen-capture-problem-in-eclipse) . When the running DDMS stand-alone as suggested there, I see i nthe windows console: W/ddms: Unable to get frame buffer: time out. I have already set the time out to 35000 in the DDMS options to no avail.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. After I disabled "Use host GPU" it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the correct answer, but when I do this the rom never boots. I just get a black window. -- edit updating to api 22 seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also cross-posted this answer in the question you linked: This works for me, also when Logcat ceases to work: When I disable and re-enable the debug mode on the device, everything is working again.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this on eclipse

```
Go to Window -> show view -> other -> android -> devices, then click **OK**
```

Now select the device which you want to take screen shots and then click **Capture Screen** button on the rightside of the **Devices** screen.

Comment: That is what I did and it is this that does not work. The DDMS perspective shows the devices tab, so I mistook the DDMS name for the devices tab.